# MATLAB curve-fitting with a custom equation

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting

I'm working on curve-fitting data which consists of two arrays:

```
t: 1, 3, 4, 7, 8, 10

P: 2.1, 4.6, 5.4, 6.1, 6.4, 6.6
```

The relationship between the two variables is given by `P = mt/(b+t)`. I'm told to determine the constants m and b by curve-fitting the equation to the data points. This should be done by writing the reciprocal of the equation and using a first-order polynomial. Here is my code:

```
t = [1 3 4 7 8 10];
P = [2.1 4.6 5.4 6.1 6.4 6.6];

p = polyfit(t, t./P, 1);


m = 1/p(1)
b = p(2)*m

tm = 1:0.01:10;
Pm = (m*tm)./(b+tm);

plot(t,P, 'o', tm, Pm)
```

The answer in the book is `m = 9.4157` and `b = 3.4418`. The code above yields `m = 8.4807` and `b = 2.6723`. What is my mistake? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Could the answers in the book be wrong? I plotted `m` and `b` from the answers: `hold on,plot(tm,(9.4157*tm)./(3.4418+tm),'r');` and at least just eyeballing it, I'd suggest your solution is closer to fitting.

Comment: I'm wondering the same. I will leave my answer as is. Thank you very much for your response, David_G.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To follow up on the comment made by @David_G, it looks like you have a better answer.  In fact, if you run the data through Curve Fitting Toolbox in MATLAB you get:

```
General model:
  f(t) = m*t/(b+t)
Coefficients (with 95% confidence bounds):
   b =       2.587  (1.645, 3.528)
   m =       8.448  (7.453, 9.443)

Goodness of fit:
  SSE: 0.1594
  R-square: 0.9888
  Adjusted R-square: 0.986
  RMSE: 0.1996
```

Your solution is almost as good:

```
Goodness of fit:
  SSE: 0.1685
  R-square: 0.9881
  Adjusted R-square: 0.9852
  RMSE: 0.2053
```

And both of them are better than the one in the book:

```
Goodness of fit:
  SSE: 0.404
  R-square: 0.9716
  Adjusted R-square: 0.9645
  RMSE: 0.3178
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Huguenot. I learned how the author of the book had arrived at his conclusion, but I am glad I stuck with my answer. Thank you again.